# java.lang.stackoverflowerror when adding to a Linked-List

Tags: java, linked-list, stack-overflow

I'm getting this problem while trying to add an object to a linkedlist (java util)
I've a **Doctor** and **Patient** class, both inherit from the abstract class **Person**

```
public abstract class Person {
    private LinkedList<Appointment> scheduledAppointments = new LinkedList<Appointment>();

    //irrelevant code

    public boolean addAppointment(Appointment appointment){
        return this.scheduledAppointments.add(appointment);
    }
```

**the participants attribute has a doctor and a patient in the linked list.**

```
public class Appointment {
    private ArrayList<Person> participants = new ArrayList<Person>();
    ...

    public Appointment(Person doctor, Person patient, int day, int month, int year, double startHour, Procedure procedure) {
        this.participants.add(doctor);
        this.participants.add(patient);
        ...
        }

    public void addAppointmentToParticipants(){
        for (Person person : participants) {
            person.addAppointment(this);
        }
    }
```

the problem occurs when i'm trying to add the Appointment to each of the participants:
**`Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate Appointment.toString()`**

when I'm debugging it, i can see that the exception occurs on the LinkedList.java, 
particularly on the **size++ line**

```
   void linkLast(E e) {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (l == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            l.next = newNode;
        size++;
        modCount++;
    }
```

I don't understand why i'm haing this problem, and what does "toString" has to do with it...

Comment: `Appointment` needs `Person` and `Person` needs `Appointment`, this can go on till you get stackoverflowerror. Remodel the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `toString()` in the error message, it looks like whatever `toString()` you have in `Appointment` embeds the string representation of `Person`, but whatever `toString()` you have in `Person` does the same for `Appointment`. This would lead to a `StackOverflowError` anytime you call `toString()`, because the string would continually expand (and the relationship is bi-directional here).

This would also make printing out your `LinkedList` impossible without encountering the error.

The solution is to make the `toString()` of one of these classes **not** embed the other's `toString()`. Better yet, you should rethink your model and determine whether you really need this bi-directional relationship.

Comment: I see what you mean, but why do toString() is called when all I'm trying to do is to add the appoitment to the list?